# Duplicate showing - Group By Rollup SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

[image: SQL Result]

I'm trying to get the Count of Students Group by Course Name

Here's the query

```
SELECT tblCOURSE.CourseTitle, Count(tblENROLLMENT.StudentID) AS 'Number Of Students' FROM tblENROLLMENT
INNER JOIN tblCOURSE on tblENROLLMENT.CourseId = tblCOURSE.CourseId
GROUP BY ROLLUP (tblENROLLMENT.CourseId, tblCOURSE.CourseTitle)
```

Started from this query and was trying to get the CourseTitle from the tblCourse Table

```
SELECT Count(StudentID) AS 'Number Of Students' FROM tblENROLLMENT
INNER JOIN tblCOURSE on tblENROLLMENT.CourseId = tblCOURSE.CourseId
GROUP BY ROLLUP (tblENROLLMENT.CourseId)
```

[image: SQL QUERY]

currently taking Fundamentals of Database Systems, any solutions?

Here are the tables

```
INSERT INTO tblCOURSE
(CourseId,CourseTitle,CourseCode,CrdtHrs) VALUES
(1,'Fundamentals of Programming','INSY2022',5),
(2,'Advanced Computer Programming','INSY2031',5),
(3,'Fundamentals of Database Systems','INSY2013',5),
(4,'Introduction to Information Systems and Society','INSY2033',4),
(5,'Introduction to Information Storage & Retrieval','INSY3093',4)



INSERT INTO tblENROLLMENT(EnrollId,CourseId,StudentID,DateofEnrollment,MidExResult,ProjectResult,FinalExResult)
VALUES
(1,1,1,'2020-01-01',20,21,50),
(2,2,2,'2020-01-01',20,27,50),
(3,3,3,'2020-01-01',20,22,50),
(4,4,4,'2020-01-01',20,20,50),
(5,5,5,'2020-01-01',20,17,50),
(6,1,6,'2020-01-01',20,10,50),
(7,2,1,'2020-01-01',20,29,50),
(8,3,1,'2020-01-01',20,28,50),
(9,4,5,'2020-01-01',20,25,50),
(10,5,1,'2020-01-01',20,50,50)
```

Comment: Looks like you need `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((tblENROLLMENT.CourseId, tblCOURSE.CourseTitle), ())`

Comment: @Charlieface okay

Comment: *`I'm trying to get the Count of Students Group by Course Name`* Why can't you use normal `group by`

Comment: @Shmiel cause I'm also trying get the total of Student taking one particular course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need `GROUPING SETS`

```sql
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(c.CourseTitle) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE c.CourseTitle END AS CourseTitle,
  COUNT(*) AS [Number Of Students]
FROM tblENROLLMENT e
INNER JOIN tblCOURSE c on e.CourseId = c.CourseId
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (e.CourseId, c.CourseTitle),
    ()
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=993702b810e0903c34dc5e190c703bcf)

The problem was that
`GROUP BY ROLLUP (tblENROLLMENT.CourseId, tblCOURSE.CourseTitle)`
is the equivalent of
`GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((tblENROLLMENT.CourseId, tblCOURSE.CourseTitle), (tblENROLLMENT.CourseId), ())`
so you end up with intermediate grouping rows also.

Note also:

- `GROUPING()` returns `1` for the Total row, so we use that to show the text `Total`. Otherwise you would get a `NULL`.
- Don't use `''` to quote column names, use `[]` instead.
- `Count(tblENROLLMENT.StudentID)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` if `StudentID` is not null.
- Use short meaningful aliases to make your query more readable.
- Likewise for good formatting.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can I get the total without using CASE, I know it's checking if there are more than one course Title's, but is there another way?

Comment: You can just return `c.CourseTitle` but then it will be `NULL` for the grouping row, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a03325026d6db42038a8733e1219a15c